# matlab: Issue reading excel binary (.xlsb) file

Tags: excel, matlab

I am trying to read in (MATLAB 7.14.0.739 (R2012a), Ubuntu 12.04, filesize ~2MB) a binary excel file containing multiple sheets but get the following error:

```
[status,sheets,xlFormat] = xlsfinfo('633933_2014-07-04_11-34-27.xlsb')
```

> status =
>
> ```
>  ''
> ```
>
> sheets =
>
> Unreadable Excel file: File contains unexpected record length.  Try
>   saving as Excel 98.
>
> xlFormat =
>
> ```
>  ''
> ```

I have a large number of these binary files so I don't want to have to resave them to another format if possible.

Comment: That works fine for me. Maybe something in Matlab is not functioning properly. Can you restart the application or even reboot your machine?

Comment: As explained in my answer, the code works on some systems which meet the requirements. I don't think this provides a useful answer.

Comment: ryguy7272 -- your comment is only useful if you are using same version of Matlab and Ubuntu.After much searching I have had to convert .xlsb to .xlsx to .csv using some python code.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation clearly states [that the support for xlsb is limited to windows systems having excel installed](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/system-requirements-for-importing-spreadsheets.html).

You may try to find some 3rd party so, python or java library which can read xlsb but I am not aware of any. Otherwise you have to switch to a different format.